# Finding a dataset for a computer vision project related to medical imaging (related to cancer/tumor)

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, dataset, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to find a dataset of medical images related to tumor/cancer, there should be images different stages of the cancer and also preferably the details about the patient, their medical history, demographics and lifestyle. Please let me know if there exists such a data set.